# Sequelize bulkCreate updates null values in the table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have a table I need to use bulkCreate (with updateOnDuplicate) to insert data into it.
Some random columns can come as null at times. It updates the previously filled values in this field to null if it is updating.

I expect it to update only the values which have a value and ignore null fields.

**Environment**

Sequelize version: 3.32.1

Node.js version: 10.17.0

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04

I have tried deleting the key/value pairs with null value in records field before bulkCreate but it is of no use. 
I can not use omitNull in this scenario as there are other ways to update this table which can accept null values.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question - what did you achieve so far, some code examples etc.

Comment: please describe more what you have already did ?

Comment: I tried deleting key/value pairs having null values from the array of objects that goes in creating bulkCreate records field but it just takes column name from the models and updates it to null @VyasArpit